# How to query and select * where a value is a INT?

Tags: php, database

This is my SQL so far and nothing is working.

```
$st = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE group = 1 ORDER BY joined ASC");
```

All I want is to Select * from my table users where group = 1 (order by...)
Problem is my group column is a int. but I cannn't retrieve any data from it. Even if I try
group = '1'

Is there any function/way to get through this issue?
THanks!

Comment: Are you saying that the code works if you remove the WHERE clause, because I see nothing wrong with your SQL and think your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: yah exactly, if I remove the where clause, it works just fine. But I need where group = 1

Comment: Oh, duh, it's because `group` is a reserved word.  Either change the name in your DB or escape it, eg (mysql): `WHERE \`group\` = 1`

Comment: ty :) but backtick didn't fixed it, I tried users.group = 1 and works perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

group is a reserved word in many SQL implementation.  Try using users.group = 1 .

- Oracle SQL reserved words : https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_keywd001.htm#SQLRF55621
- MySQL reserved words : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html
- MSSQL reserved words : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, stop using `select *`

When writing your query, enter all the column names (or alias them if you want them to be called something different). For eg:

```
select
   userID,
   nickname,
   email as loginEmail
from
// ... etc etc
```

It also seems that you are using a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) `group` as a column name. You need to either backtick this (mySQL uses the ` character) to tell the database that you mean it as a column/table name and not an actual function like this:

```
select
    userID,
    nickname,
    email as loginEmail,
    `group`
from
    sometable
where
    `group`=1
```